# Phonegap application development in Android/ios

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I created a simple mobile app using phonegap.I successfully deployed the app in Android and ios.Now I am doing changes to "index.html" in Android. but those changes are not included in ios "index.html".there are 3 "index.html" files within the project.

1. {project}/www/index.html
2. {project}/platforms/android/assets/www/index.html
3. {project}/platforms/ios/www/index.html

As I understood if we done a change to a file,that should available to other OSs as well,As example if I done a to "index.html". that change should be available to ios "index.html" as well.but here it is not happening. am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you should edit the project index.html -> {project}/www/index.html and when you make changes you need to rebuild your project which will copy them into the Android/iOS folders as well as inject the phonegap/cordova.js files for that platform